# Unable to connect to postgres(running in docker) from pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have postgres running in docker with this command:

```
docker run --name=my-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abc -e POSTGRES_USER=xyz -d postgres
```

Then I try to connect to it using pgadmin. But I get error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Di you export the necessary Ports

Comment: export means? I provided the needed details on connection form, like port, user name, password etc.

Comment: port 5432  must be open  on localhost, so you should check if there us postgres listening